# How can I bind a polymer behavior to a child element?

Tags: polymer

I am reading about [Behaviors in Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/behaviors).

I copy/pasted the example for the `highlight-behavior.html`:

```
<script>
HighlightBehavior = {

  properties: {
    isHighlighted: {
      type: Boolean,
      value: false,
      notify: true,
      observer: '_highlightChanged'
    }
  },

  listeners: {
    click: '_toggleHighlight'
  },

  created: function() {
    console.log('Highlighting for ', this, 'enabled!');
  },

  _toggleHighlight: function() {
    this.isHighlighted = !this.isHighlighted;
  },

  _highlightChanged: function(value) {
    this.toggleClass('highlighted', value);
  }

};
```

Then, in my element i have the following (just the important parts):

```
<link rel="import" href="highlight-behavior.html">

<dom-module id="highlighting-test">
  <template>
    <style>
        :host {
            display: block;
            background-color: red;
        }

        :host.highlighted {
            background-color: green;
        }

      .highlighted {
        background-color: green;
      }
    </style>

  <h1>Click anywhere here to toggle highlighting!</h1>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'highlighting-test',
      behaviors: [HighlightBehavior]
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Now the problem is that the toggling of the `highlighted` class works when clicking inside the host element but it is not highlighting just the `h1` element. It is adding the `highlighted` class to the host element.

This is how it is rendered in the browser:

```
<highlighting-test class="highlighted">
  <h1 class="style-scope highlighting-test">Click anywhere here to toggle highlighting!</h1>
</highlighting-test>
```

When clicking I indeed see that it toggles the `highlighted` class on the host element `highlighting-test` and the background changes.

How can I make sure that the highlighting behavior is applied to just the `h1` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.toggleClass(className, bool, this.$.id_of_element)`

Comment: Not working. I get "Uncaught TypeError: `this.$.myclass.toggleClass` is not a function".

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
_highlightChanged: function(value) {
    this.toggleClass('highlighted', value);
}
```

to:

```
_highlightChanged: function(value) {
    this.$.hId.toggleClass('highlighted', value);
}
```

And in HTML add an ID to H1:

```
 <h1 id="hId">Click anywhere here to toggle highlighting!</h1>
```